# Dev Substrate Node at Capacity for WS Connections, how to flush?

Tags: rpc, api, websocket, dev, javascript

I'm running a node in dev mode: `./substrate/target/release/substrate --dev --tmp --ws-external`

My client connection code:

```
provider = new WsProvider(wsProvider)
api = await new ApiPromise({ provider }).isReady;
```

I am testing an app using polkadot js api, and often connecting via ws. This has worked fine, except now when I connect it says the node is at full capacity:

`2022-04-19 17:03:12 Unable to build WebSocket connection WS Error <Capacity>: Unable to add another connection to the event loop.`

I assumed the `disconnect` event is fired when the client app closes, I'm not sure why it is full.

`netstat` shows a few ESTABLISHED connections from my ip, not sure why as I'm not currently even running the app.

Comment: Can you try adding: `--ws-max-out-buffer-capacity=99999 --rpc-max-payload=99999` or something similar? Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: Pro tip: --dev implies --tmp for a while now, so it's redundant to use both :)

Comment: Can you also comment on where this node is hosted? Is it local and behind a firewall? do you see any peers or other connections? Can you provide detail on what you think those WS connections come from?

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't update for a while. I just left it exposed for testing. I was using ufw but not blocking port 9944. Currently I'm migrating to a k8s setup with multiple ksm nodes being proxied by an nginx server, so that should be better.

Comment: How often do you connecting via WS? Are you closing the connections or keeping the open?

Comment: I've got an app with a constant connection as well as clients who can connect from local html/js app. From the app I'm only calling `new WsProvider(wsUrl || 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944')` once. From the client, shouldn't it disconnect on window close?

Comment: If it helps you need to check if you have a health check running, sometimes that causes an influx of connection requests which overloads your connection limit

I am not sure closing the window disconnects the connection, perhaps someone else can confirm

Answer (score 1):

As @Shawn mentioned you can try `--ws-max-out-buffer-capacity=99999`

That worked for us

Also, I confirmed that the ws connection disconnects at either refresh or if you navigate away from the tab

You can see my discussion with Jago [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4829)

As noted, there has been a lot of work done on the `0.9.22` release to use the new `jsonrpsee` client that improves connections

Some nodes are already running this client